# pthread_create differences in linux kernel 2.4.20 and 2.4.36

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have some code on two systems running `kernel 2.4.20` and `kernel 2.4.38`.
They both have `gcc 3.2.2` and `glibc 2.3.2`

Under `kernel 2.4.38`, the pthread_t handles aren't being reused. Under a heavy load test the application crashes once the handles reach `0xFFFFFFFF`.

( I suspected this in the first place because the app crashes in deployments where IT uses a network port scanner- the threads are created for handling socket connections )

**This simple example recreates the problem:**

```
void* ThreadProc(void* param)
{
    usleep(10000);
    printf(" Thread 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self());
    usleep(10000);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t sThread;

    while(1)
    {
      pthread_create(&sThread, NULL, ThreadProc, NULL); 
      printf("Created 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)sThread);  
      pthread_join(sThread, NULL);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Under 2.4.20:

```
    Created 0x40838cc0
     Thread 0x40838cc0
    Created 0x40838cc0
     Thread 0x40838cc0
    Created 0x40838cc0
     Thread 0x40838cc0
...and on and on...
```

Under 2.4.36:

```
    Created 0x4002
     Thread 0x4002
    Created 0x8002
     Thread 0x8002
    Created 0xc002
     Thread 0xc002
...keeps growing...
```

How can I get `kernel 2.4.36` to recycle handles? Unfortunately I can't change kernel easily.
Thanks!

Comment: Greetings to the past! I don't think that depending in your program on such a kernel behaviour is a good idea, you should rather fix your program.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: The program is fine; `pthread_join` should release all thread resources. The problem is that, on that particular kernel version, it apparently doesn't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: What makes you think that? To me it just looks like it is handing out a different handle each time, something that is perfectly fine, even when the previous handle has been freed. Just like a=malloc(5);free(a);a==malloc(5); must not be true.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Because "Under a heavy load test the application crashes once the handles reach 0xFFFFFFFF". That implies that the handles are never being reused.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I don't expect the same handle every time, I just want them to be reused at some point. My app create a new thread for each incoming socket, so it crashes after a few weeks because it runs out of thread handles.
As an aside kernel 2.6.35 also works properly (like 2.4.20). Unfortunately I can't use it!

Comment: @Scott: When it really does not reuse the handles (you should confirm that), then you are seeing a kernel bug, so you can't "get 2.4.36 to recycle handles" unless you fix the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your observations are correct, only two possible solutions exist.

Either

1. Upgrade the kernel. This may or may not be feasible for you.
2. Recycle threads within your application.

Option 2 is something you can do even if the kernel is misbehaving.  You can hold a pool of threads that remain in a sleeping state when not being used.  Thread pools are a widely known software engineering pattern (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).  This is probably the better solution for you.

Comment: There's always `3. back-port a fix from a future kernel version and rebuild your own kernel`

Comment: @Kevin A. Naudé: Yes, I'll probably have to implement a thread pool. I'm still hoping someone will know of a simple workaround for kernel 2.4.36.
Like I said, I can't change kernel easily. (including building my own)

Comment: @Scott: If you can't even build a patched kernel that fixes the problem, then you have no hope of fixing the kernel.  It seems that thread pooling may be your best (maybe only) option.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't joining my threads properly in the load test.

When I ran the load test again, the thread handles reached 0xFFFFF002 then rolled over to 0x1002 and carried on happily.

Moral of the story: Make dead sure your threads are joined or detached!